# ProgressBar in an AppWidget

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-appwidget

I ran into an interesting situation with using a ProgressBar in an App Widget...  The documentation (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html) says that ProgressBar is a supported widget class...

I have no problem getting the ProgressBar to display in my App Widget but the problem is that I want it to only be displayed as visual feedback to the user when background processing is happening.

On ImageViews I do this via RemoteViews.setViewVisibility() and everything works fine.  However, with ProgressBar I get an exception saying that ProgressBar can't use this method.

Is this intentional or is this a bug?  Is there any way to workaround this problem?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

An even simpler idea, is to put the progress bar inside some container (say a linear layout) and show/hide the container.

Answer (score 12):

It might be a bug. There's a particular annotation (`@RemotableViewMethod`) you need in the Java source code of Android itself to mark a method as being available via `RemoteViews`. `View` has this for `setVisibility()`, but `ProgressBar` overrides that method and does not have the annotation on its own edition. If `@RemotableViewMethod` is not inherited, and the override "undoes" the annotation, that would explain the symptom you see.

A workaround is to use two app widget layouts and choose the one you want (with or without `ProgressBar`) when you create your `RemoteViews` object when updating your app widget.

I'll make a note to try to replicate this and, if I see the same thing, I'll post an issue on it on the [Android issue tracker](http://b.android.com).

Comment: Thanks for the info and the workaround!  

Just as an FYI, I am currently compiling against the 1.5 SDK so it may have been fixed in a later version.

Comment: Probably not, since I was looking at more current code (via Google Code Search) when writing the answer.

Comment: It is still not working from API Level 8 on. But the tip to use an additional layout is working :)