# Custom ProgressBar in AppWidget (RemoteViews) - doable?

Tags: android, widget, progress-bar, android-appwidget

I am trying to create a custom indeterminate ProgressBar for use in an AppWidget - should be supported as RemoteViews can handle ProgressBar - but how do I declare the animated drawable that I want to use in place of the standard system provided animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not doable - frame animated and other widgets not supported as a remoteview. I ended up overlaying a regular indeterminate ProgressBar over my static AppWidget image - that is available in remoteview...

Comment: note that you must use the progressbar in a [very specific way](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2415782/509498)

Answer (score 2):

In code/xml you can declare the progressbar and set visible:

```
android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/spin_progress"
```

The spin_progress.xml would animate the image as rotating.

```
<animated-rotate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/imagetorotate"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"/>
```